# limit of sequence of functions

Tags: calculus

Suppose

$$ f_n = \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n x^{\frac{1}{n}}} $$

What is $\lim_{n \to \infty } f_n $ ??

I am having hard time with this sequence which seems like it is going to be something like the exponential, but I cannot see how to simplify it and make it look like the exponential. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is x ? is x in (0,1), what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Recall that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n$ both exist then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_nb_n$=($\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n$)($\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n$)